# Failing at Datatable's w/AJAX+jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
    // DB table to use
    $table = 'members';

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'UID';

    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'UID', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Username',  'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Registered',   'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Activation',     'dt' => 3 ),
        //array( 'db' => 'Online',     'dt' => 4 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Email',     'dt' => 4 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Country',     'dt' => 5 ),
        array( 'db' => 'IP',     'dt' => 6 ),
        array( 'db' => 'Suspended',     'dt' => 7 )
    );

$column_query = "SELECT $columns FROM $table ORDER BY ASC $primaryKey";
$column_rs = $conn->execute($column_rs);
```

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html - Following this.

My table.....

```
   <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>UID</th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Joined</th>
                                    <th>Activated</th>
                                    <!-- <th>Online</th> -->
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Country</th>
                                    <th>IP</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
```

I don't know what to do, I'm so terrible at jQuery

And the error I get when attempting this.

- removed image, I get error: 7 http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

My ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a_members').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "js_table.php"
    } );
} );
```

I've never done jquery, let-alone datatable related jquery.

Comment: does your query working? i dont think so :O

Comment: `$column_query = "SELECT $columns FROM $table ORDER BY ASC $primary";` add `or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());` see if your query even works.

Comment: Are you returning (`echo/print`) the query data (*provided the query is being run successfully*) ?

Comment: provided the query is successful, did you even gave a response? eg. like: `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: I don't have a json_encode($data) line. Friend told me to remove it because I don't need it....

Comment: @Skewled, I never got an error.

Comment: You do have an error, your server is faulting and returning 500 which is why the code isn't running or your jquery isn't returning anything. The problem I believe is with how you are trying to use the array in the select statement of your query, it should be throwing an error on that. You can't just expect it to use each element of the array by default like you currently have it setup.